# []byte to []int or []bool

Tags: go, type-conversion, slice, bit

Let's say I have a `[]byte` and for the sake of making my life easier I want to convert it in a `[]int` or `[]bool` in the following way:

Let's say I start with `[]byte{0x41}`, that is `0b01000001`. Now, what I would like to obtain is something like:

```
[]int{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1}
```

or

```
[]bool{f,t,f,f,f,f,f,t}
```

I guess I could cycle with something like this:

```
mybyte & (1 << pos)
```

but I was looking for a more compact approach.

Comment: So what is the question? If you are looking for some magical feature or syntactic sugar: Stop looking, there is none. Write loops and shifts. If you are looking for a package doing this for you: Stop looking at SO.

Comment: What a nice comment.... Since I am rather new to the language and I am aware of `strconv.FormatInt( a []byte turned into int , 2)` that returns me a string with the binary representation as a string, I was just looking for a similar, more compact, approach. Thank you, @Volker, take care.

Comment: What's the purpose of converting `[]byte` to `[]bool`? You want to be able to test for individual bits?

Comment: The []byte is the output of a modbus read of a bunch of coils (that is: individual bits). By representing them as a []int or []bool I get to "explain" better what I am doing to those bits, instead of doing shifts all the time. In a sense: it's clearer as a representation to both the end user and the developer.

Answer (score 8):

There is no ready function in the standard lib that would do that. Here's a possible solution using a loop:

```
func convert(data []byte) []bool {
    res := make([]bool, len(data)*8)
    for i := range res {
        res[i] = data[i/8]&(0x80>>byte(i&0x7)) != 0
    }
    return res
}
```

You explained you want to convert `[]byte` to `[]bool` because you treat the input as a set of individual bits.

In that case just use [`big.Int`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int). It has [`Int.Bit()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Bit) and [`Int.SetBit()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.SetBit) methods to get and set a bit at a given position. To "initialize" a `big.Int` value with the raw `[]byte`, use [`Int.SetBytes()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.SetBytes). If you modify / manipulate the `big.Int`, you may get back the raw bytes using [`Int.Bytes()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Bytes).

See this example:

```
data := []byte{0x41, 0x01}
fmt.Println("intput bytes:", data)

bi := big.NewInt(0)
bi.SetBytes(data)
fmt.Println("data:", bi.Text(2))

fmt.Println("7. bit before:", bi.Bit(7))
bi.SetBit(bi, 7, 1)
fmt.Println("7. bit after:", bi.Bit(7))
fmt.Println("data:", bi.Text(2))
fmt.Println("output bytes:", bi.Bytes())
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Ybi3RCExbwM)):

```
intput bytes: [65 1]
data: 100000100000001
7. bit before: 0
7. bit after: 1
data: 100000110000001
output bytes: [65 129]
```